# Popups during onload getting blocked - ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, onload

I have this script running during page load, but it is getting blocked (Popup) of course.
It is not possible to use a click event, so I need to have it during onload.

Any ideas?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "win", "window.open('" + url + "');", true);
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a new window? A popup in form of a dialog would be easier to implement and might not be seen as intrusive as a popup.

Comment: what do you mean by blocked ?

Comment: Preferable I would like to treat it as a regular page, therefore this question.

Comment: One other option would be to create a new page (tab) from code-behind.

Comment: so you mean on page load, you want to redirect to another page instead of displaying popup right ?

Comment: The following are my scenario:
1. The user click "Send Order" 2. Code-Behind action and if everything is validated the user will be sent to a confirmation page (My) and here I would like a new tab (Not an ugly popup-window) to be opened during page load

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function:

```
Public Shared Function WindowScript( URL As String,  Name As String,  Width As String,  Height As String,  MenuBar As Boolean,  Toolbar As Boolean, Location As Boolean,  StatusBar As Boolean,  Copyhistory As Boolean,  ScrollBar As Boolean,  Resizable As Boolean) As String

        Dim ret As String = "var left = (screen.width/2)-(" + Width + "/2); var top = (screen.height/2)-(" + Height + "/2); javascript:void window.open ('"
    ret = ret & URL & "', '" & Name & "', '"

    ret = ret & "resizable=1,"
    ret = ret & "width=" & Width & ","
    ret = ret & "height=" & Height & ","
    ret = ret & "resizable=" & (If((Resizable), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "menuBar=" & (If((MenuBar), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "toolbar=" & (If((Toolbar), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "location=" & (If((Location), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "statusBar=" & (If((StatusBar), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "copyhistory=" & (If((Copyhistory), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "scrollBar=" & (If((ScrollBar), "1", "0")) & ","
    ret = ret & "scrollbars=" & (If((ScrollBar), "yes", "no")) & ","
    ret = ret & ",top='+top+',left='+left)"
    Return ret

End Function
```

This works for me in any browser.